# Async.series: Variable is undefined outside of function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

I'm new to Node/Javascript and trying to grab a url `audioLink` by loading another url `songLink`. I would then add them to a new object `rapSong`. To achieve this I am using async series so that the calls will be happen asynchronously. I have tried other methods such as using async waterfall and just callbacks with no success.

`audioLink` is `undefined` unless I am within the `getAudioLink` function. Also the functions in the async.series do not run in the correct order. Any advice?

```
  //for each song..
songLinkElem.each(function(i, s) {             
            var songName = StringUtils.removeWhiteSpacesAndNewLines($(s).children(".title_with_artists").text());
            var songLink = $(s).attr("href");
            var audioLink;

            async.series([
                function(callback){
                    function getAudioLink(songLink, callback){
                    request(songLink, function(err,resp,body){
                       $ = cheerio.load(body);
                        var audioElem = $(body).find(".audio_link > a");
                        var audioLink = audioElem.attr("href"); 
                        return callback(audioLink);
                    });
                }

                    getAudioLink(songLink, function(resp){
                        audioLink = resp;
                        console.log("one");
                    })

                    console.log("two");
                    callback();  
                }, 
                function(callback){
                    var rapSong = new Song(songName, artistLink, songLink, audioLink);
                     rapArtist.addSong(rapSong); 
                    console.log("three");
                    callback();
                }],
                function(err, result){
                   console.log("four");
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your first `async.series` function, you shouldn't call its callback until the callback for `getAudioLink` is called.

So move the code that follows the `getAudioLink` call *inside* its callback:

```
getAudioLink(songLink, function(resp){
    audioLink = resp;
    console.log("one");
    console.log("two");
    callback();  
});
```

That way the `async.series` won't proceed until after `audioLink` is set.